# Conversion of raster to polygon

Tags: arcobjects, c#, raster-conversion

Using C# and ArcObjects, what is the recommended way to convert a raster file into a polygon.  I need this for calling the Near tool so that I can move a station which may be inland to the nearest water feature.  I have googled and really not found anything useful yet.  There is a lot for taking a polygon to a Raster but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to avoid geoprocessing (which is typically slow), have a look at **IConversionOp** interface:

http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//002400000016000000

Haven't used it myself but it seems to offer what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is calling the [Raster to Polygon (Conversion)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//001200000008000000) geoprocessing tool. Note that your raster must be of the integer type.

If you want to convert your entire raster to a polygon you can use the [Int (Spatial Analyst)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#//009z0000008z000000.htm) geoprocessing tool.

You can use the [Con (Spatial Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000005000000) geoprocessing tool to select parts of your input raster and produce an integer raster at the same time. This is useful, for example, if you want to create a polygon representing areas within the raster that have values greater than an input value (e.g. all elevations above 500m).

Comment: Radar!  That looks great and I think I actually looked at that.  I have one problem, though, how do I create a blank FeatureSet.  That was one of my sticking points!